# How do I add a table to an existing schema with existing tables in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table from another MySQL Workbench Connection and Schema that I wish to import into this Connection and an existing database into an existing schema with existing tables.

I exported the table I wanted into .sql form. Now I am trying to import that .sql file into the existing schema with existing tables. When I try to do this via the Data Import tool. I get an error message that says Table X.Y does not exist. Of course it does not exist. I am trying to create it! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take the `CREATE TABLE` (and possibly `INSERT INTO`) statement(s) from the .sql file and execute them. You can open the file or copy paste the content.

Comment: There is no CREATE TABLE statement in the .sql file that was  created by the export. The importer is complaining about line 22 which says "LOCK TABLES 'opschemtable' WRITE;  Should I comment or change that statement?

Comment: Then you need to export again and make sure you export the `CREATE TABLE` statements too. I cannot look it up right now but there should be some check boxes or radio buttons about (also) exporting the structure/schema/`CREATE` statements or similar AFAIR.

Comment: OK, I got a CREATE TABLE statement it likes BUT it is complaining with a different error message: ERROR 1005: Can't create table WRONGSCHEMA.opschemtable (errno. 150),  How do I get it to create a table in RIGHTSCHEMA. I don't see anything that sets a default database/schema.